# GeoFire: Write location and data atomically?

Tags: firebase, transactions, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

Using GeoFire with Firebase, I can only create the geodata with `setLocation`. As is recommend with GeoFire, the actual data entry being referenced goes elsewhere in the database. So when creating a new entry I need to use GeoFire to write the geodata under one reference, and an ordinary `setValue` for rest of the data on another reference. Is there any way to write to both of these locations atomically? Both transactions and multi-location updates seem inadequate because of the way GeoFire writes the geodata internally.

Comment: You cannot. Additionally, you're going to need the record id created by writing the data to save it in your GeoFire info. So write the data sourced first and then call setLocation().

Comment: That's how I'm doing it now. Was that a design decision? I know the rationale for separating the two but it would still be nice to create them at the same time.

Comment: GeoFire is an OSS lib, not part of the core SDK. I don't think there's any design decision so much as technical limitations. Maybe a feature request on the lib would be a good idea?